# Javascript Regular expression to allow negative double value?

Tags: javascript, regex

Hi I have e regular expression which helps me to validate user input.

It only allows positive numbers with 2 decimal places, this is my regex:

```
^[0-9]+\.[0-9][0-9]$
```

I want this to function for negative numbers as well.
How can I change the regexp to allow negative values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be as follows:

```
^(\-)?[0-9]+\.[0-9][0-9]$
```

Answer (score 0):

Think this will work:

```
^(-?)[0-9]+\.[0-9][0-9]$
```