# JavaScript: Retrieve negative floating point number from string of mutiple sums

Tags: javascript, regex, floating-point

I have a simple app that allows me to caculate the total amount invoiced and deposited in a route. However I want to allow the user to input multiple values in a single input field; e.g:
`500+50+36.5-45.2-10`.

I have written a function that will retrieve this input and then `split` this string into elements of an array at the `+` sign and immediately parse the values to numbers and then add them and return the total the user inputs into each individual field. This is all well as long as the user does no use any sign other than `+`.

I have searched the use of `regexp`:

- [regular expression in javascript for negative floating point number result stored in array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19000843/regular-expression-in-javascript-for-negative-floating-point-number-result-store)
- [Javascript Regular expression to allow negative double value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13249971/javascript-regular-expression-to-allow-negative-double-value?rq=1)

but none of the results seem to work.
How could I make my code retrieve the values so that the negative values get passed into the array as negative values?

Here is a snippet of my Js code:
For the full code, visit my [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MMendes/eKeLt/15/).

```
totalInvoiced: function () {

    var a = A.invoiced.value;
    var value1Arr = []; 
        value1Arr = a.split("+").map(parseFloat);
    var value1 = 0;
        value1Arr.forEach(function (value) {
        value1 += value;
    });
```

Comment: Works only if the user inputs only one negative number. It works, however messy, if you complete the first parameter of `replace` as `a.replace(/(\-)/g, "+-").split("+")` and set the `g` attribute to the `regexp`. Thanks ;)

Comment: Yes, I fixed it a few seconds later. :) No need to escape `-` there or use parentheses. I added an answer already, as you see can below.

Comment: Both solutions work in the end, but `/\+|(?=-)/` is much cleaner code-wise. Thanks ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I really like PhistucK's solution, but here an alternative with regex:

```
value1Arr = a.split(/(?=\+|\-)/);
```

This will split it, but keeps the delimiter, so the result will be:

```
["500", "+50", "+36.5", "-45.2", "-10"]
```

Comment: Perhaps `value1Arr = a.split(/\+|(?=-)/);` so the pluses are dropped? This is what I originally wanted to suggest, but I did not know about `?=`, I tried `?:`. Thank you for teaching me this trick!

Comment: No, it drops the pluses, while yours keeps the pluses. Yes, it will eventually be the same when parsed, of course, if that is what you meant.

Comment: Yes that was what I meant, after parsed :)

Answer (score 2):

A bit dirty, but maybe `a.replace(/-/g, "+-").split("+")`, this way, you add a plus before every minus, since the negative numbers just basically lack an operator.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this pattern that splits on + sign or before - sign:

```
var str = '500+50+36.5-45.2-10';

console.log(str.split(/\+|(?=-)/));
```